# Is it possible to store the data from two separate forms with the Django admin?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have been asked to make the data from two separate models editable via django admin. *(I know this isn't a good use of django admin, it's just something I've been asked to do)*

Here are the relevant models:

#### models

```
class RateCategoryGroup(ValueModel):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("organization",)


class RateCategoryGroupMembership(TimeStampedModel):
    membership = models.OneToOneField(
        "organizations.OrganizationMembership", related_name="rate_category_group_membership", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey("RateCategoryGroup", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="group_memberships")


class FeeEarnerProfile(TimeStampedModel):
    membership = models.OneToOneField(
        "OrganizationMembership", related_name="fee_earner_profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

I have found that I'm able to expose the form with the following:

#### admin

```
class FeeEarnerProfileAdmin(VersionAdmin):
    change_form_template = "admin/organizations/fee_earner_profile/change_form.html"

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url="", extra_context=None):
        rate_category_group_instance = RateCategoryGroup.objects.get(
            group_memberships__membership__fee_earner_profile__id=object_id
        )
        rate_category_group_form = RateCategoryGroupForm(instance=rate_category_group_instance)
        return super().change_view(
            request, object_id, form_url, extra_context={"rate_category_group_form": rate_category_group_form}
        )
```

#### template

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}


{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {{ rate_category_group_form }}
{% endblock %}
```

However, clicking the button to submit this form will only include information from the `FeeEarnerProfileAdmin` form and nothing from my `RateCategoryGroupForm`

How can I get the changed data from the `RateCategoryGroupForm` to be included in the request?

Answer (score 0):

To store the data from two separate forms in the Django admin, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a custom admin form that combines the fields from both models.
2. Override the `save_model` method in the admin class to handle saving data for both models.

Here's how you can achieve this:

1. Create a custom admin form that combines fields from both `FeeEarnerProfile` and `RateCategoryGroup` models:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import FeeEarnerProfile, RateCategoryGroup

class CustomAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    rate_category_group_value = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = FeeEarnerProfile
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        fee_earner_profile = super().save(commit=False)

        # Get the rate_category_group_value from the form data
        rate_category_group_value = self.cleaned_data.get('rate_category_group_value')

        # Check if RateCategoryGroup exists with the provided value or create a new one
        rate_category_group, _ = RateCategoryGroup.objects.get_or_create(value=rate_category_group_value)

        # Save the FeeEarnerProfile and set the rate_category_group
        fee_earner_profile.save()
        fee_earner_profile.rate_category_group = rate_category_group
        fee_earner_profile.save()

        return fee_earner_profile
```

2. Update your `FeeEarnerProfileAdmin` to use the custom admin form and override the `save_model` method:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import FeeEarnerProfile
from .forms import CustomAdminForm

class FeeEarnerProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomAdminForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Save the FeeEarnerProfile using the custom form's save method
        fee_earner_profile = form.save()

        # Save the RateCategoryGroup using the related_name 'group_memberships'
        rate_category_group = fee_earner_profile.rate_category_group
        rate_category_group_membership, _ = RateCategoryGroupMembership.objects.get_or_create(membership=obj)
        rate_category_group_membership.group = rate_category_group
        rate_category_group_membership.save()

admin.site.register(FeeEarnerProfile, FeeEarnerProfileAdmin)
```

With these changes, when you submit the form in the Django admin, the data from both the `FeeEarnerProfile` and `RateCategoryGroup` forms will be saved correctly. The custom form will handle saving the `RateCategoryGroup`, and the `FeeEarnerProfileAdmin` will handle saving the `FeeEarnerProfile` and its relationship with the `RateCategoryGroup`.